# How to retrieve all email addresses from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

How to retrieve all email addresses in Active Directory? Will the following filter return the desired data?

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(mail=*))
```

Comment: This filter expression will return all **user** objects that have an e-mail address defined, yes

Comment: @marc_s is that return same output  if i use (objectCategory=person) or (objectCategory=contact) ?